# Access facebook profile picture using javascript api

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to access all comments for a post.I am able to access the commenter's name and message but not their profile picture.

Can anyone tell me how to get it using javascript API?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow !   Please read the FAQ section about how to ask a proper question.  Basically what you are missing is the code that you have written so far and what exactly is happening? are you getting an error or just not the response you expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by leveraging the Field Expansion API like this:

```
/{page_id}/posts?fields=comments.summary(true).fields(message,from{id,name,picture})&limit=1
```

Have a look at an [example with the Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=facebook%2Fposts%3Ffields%3Dcomments.summary(true).fields(message%2Cfrom%7Bid%2Cname%2Cpicture%7D)%26limit%3D1&version=v2.5).